# Check if an email address is valid in OSX SDK

Tags: objective-c, macos, email-validation, appkit

I am building an app for `Mac OS X` that brings in email addresses from an Excel file.

Is there any method in the `SDK` that would allow me to check if an email is valid, e.g. a `Hard Bounce`? Something similar to using `ping` but for emails?

Comment: Nope. Or, at least, if there is, there shouldn't be. Any sane SMTP server won't tell you whether an e-mail actually maps to an account, or you'd be able to use that functionality to brute force a listing of the user accounts. So, in practice, this 'ping' functionality wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: I have seen some online services that do this. They must be using some network method to check the response...

Comment: @ParthianShot - True. I guess I am just looking for something similar to getting a Hard bounce in Mailchimp or other bulk mail senders. But, I am assuming that can only happen if you try sending them mail.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't just checking that the format of the e-mail address is valid, and there's an SMTP server listening for the domain (by doing a DNS query for an MX record)? That seems like the easiest reasonable thing to do, short of actually sending an e-mail.

Comment: @ParthianShot - I am not sure. It looks like they are not very reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

The only way to test if an email address will bounce is to try sending it an email and see if it bounces. It isn't possible to do this directly from most desktop computers, as most residential ISPs block outbound SMTP, and there is no method in the Mac OS X frameworks to do so.

Comment: Worth noting that testing e-mail addresses this way can get your mailserver's IP blacklisted. So, you want to make sure **most** of the mail you're sending is to actual people, and you definitely want to make sure you don't use lists of e-mail addresses slurped from the internet (partly because that's illegal, partly because those lists sometimes contain addresses that only exist to help identify spammers).